# How to update react state immediately in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have tons of logic in react.useEffect and I want to update state whenever props.match changes like this :

```
const [ start, setStart] = useState(0);
const [ end, setEnd] = useState(5);
```

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
if (!subcategory && !location && !search) {
                setStart(0);
                setEnd(5);
                if (url.search) {
                        Axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/getAll${url.search}`)
                            .then((res) => {
                                setLen(res.data.length);
                                const sliced = res.data.slice(props.start, props.end);
                                props.fetchData(sliced);
                                setStart(end);
                                setEnd(prev=> prev + 5);
                            })
                } else {
                        Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/getAll')
                            .then((res) => {
                                setLen(res.data.length);
                                const sliced = res.data.slice(props.start, props.end);
                                props.fetchData(sliced);
                                setStart(end);
                                setEnd(prev=> prev + 5);
                            })
                }
                return undefined;
            }
        },
        [ props.match ]
    );
```

In order to my logic to work I need to have both start and end states equal to 0 and 5 by order and it always updates them before axios get them .

I've tried using another useEffect but it didn't work . I dont want to use class component also .

How can I update state immediately in functional component ?

Comment: maybe, `useEffect(()=>{ if (start === 0 && end === 5) { ...axios logic here } }, [start, end])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this big problem by having two useEffects like this :

```
    const [ start, setStart ] = useState(0);
    const [ end, setEnd ] = useState(5);
    const [ urlChanged, setUrlChanged ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setStart(0);
            setEnd(5);
            setUrlChanged((prev) => !prev);
        },
        [ props.match ]
    );

    useEffect(
        () => {
            // logic using the latest end and start states
        },
        [ urlChanged ]
    );
```

It's weird nobody has ever answered this question on stackoverflow the way I did solve it because everybody say to use class component this.setState({state : '' , callback function}) .

Answer (score 1):

To immediately use useEffect, similar to the class lifecycle componentDidMount use `useEffect(()=>{},[])` with nothing in the dependency array.

Otherwise you need to pass in all external vars that you depend on. start, end,

Your first usage of useState seem redundant because you already set them to 0 and 5. Every props.match will re-set useState

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
if (!subcategory && !location && !search) {
            setStart(0); // redundant
            setEnd(5); // redundant
```